# When I install Anaconda,some files are not installed

Tags: python, installation, anaconda

When I install Anaconda, installed files look like this. The other files are not installed and I can't reach Anaconda Navigator or else.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from the picture you work on Windows 10, I think that the issue is connected with special characters in the directory you try to install anaconda to. So when prompted where to install anaconda, choose a directory that only contains the usual Latin characters (spaces are not an issue).

If it is your computer's name that contains the special character (as was the case with me), it might be hard to find such a directory. Here are three things that might work:

1. Install to the Documents folder, as this has (for some reason) the directory `C:\Doc Folders\` and omits the `Users\Username` in between.
2. It might be possible to change your computer's username, for example, the way they did it here: https://thegeekpage.com/rename-user-folder/
3. Install to an external drive. This, however, requires you to be connected to the drive any time you use Anaconda unless you manage to move the application to your local drive.

I hope I could help!

Matthaeus